# Convert substring to int in golang

Tags: string, go, integer

I have this variable:

```
danumber := "542353242"
```

and want to extract a character from the string and operate with it as a number.
Tried this:

```
int(danumber[0])
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the expected result of this supposed operation? 5 or 53 (an US-ASCII code for the character "5")? I'm asking because "extract a character ... and operate with it as a number" can be interpreted as if you'd like to get the character *code* and not convert "5" to an integer 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your expression gives you is the [character code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) for the digit. To convert the character to the character's value, subtract `0`'s  character code from it:

```
int(danumber[0] - '0') // in your example, this is: 53 - 48
```

If you want to convert multiple digits, I would recommend using the [`strconv`](https://godoc.org/strconv) package:

```
number, err := strconv.Atoi(danumber[0:2]) // convert first two characters to int
```

Comment: thanx, I'll try it. Could you explain why would this work? What about a sub string like danumber[0:3] ?

Comment: @Perroloco: Updated. Yes, `danumber[0:3]` would work as well with `strconv.Atoi`.